# Pass Javascript Object Without Named Function Running during Instantiation

Tags: javascript

If we have a Javascript object structured as follows:

```
var p = 'param'

obj: {
    a: 'a',
    b: b(p)
}

function b(parameter){
    console.log(true)
}
```

How can we pass `b` with the object without `b` running during `obj`'s instantiation?

Comment: ignoring the syntax errors, `b: b.bind(obj,p)`

Comment: Or, if you don't actually care about the `this` context (if you don't know what that means, you probably **do**) you can just write `b: b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
"B": function() {return b(p);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
function b(parameter){
    return function(parameter){
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
var obj = {
  a: 'a',
  get b(){ return b(p); }
};
```

```js
var obj = {
  a: 'a',
  get b(){ return b(p); }
};
function b(parameter) {
  console.log(true)
}
```